# dataGrid search with sql LIKE query not working as it should

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have a dataGrid in my app.I am using a TextChanged event to filter the data grid.I have four text boxes for filtering.I am using a SQL query with LIKE.
When I use the filter with only two text boxes,this method works fine.But if I use three,of four(as I need four) it does not filter the data grid right.It doesn't show all the matches,and when I clear the text box,it doesn't reset the dataGrid to show the whole table.

My XAML:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="227" Width="990" Margin="0,202,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="200" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding type}" Width="300"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding city}" Width="250" />

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place" Binding="{Binding place}" Width="*" />


                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

My code for TextChanged event:

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            sc.Open();
            string query_search = "SELECT * FROM object WHERE name LIKE @name AND type LIKE @type AND city LIKE @city AND place LIKE @place";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query_search, sc);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + textBoxPlace.Text + "%");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "%" + textBoxType.Text + "%");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "%" + textBoxCity.Text + "%");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", "%" + textBoxPlace.Text + "%");


            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dataGridSearch.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            sc.Close();
        }
```

Also,at the opening of the window,I have a method that fills the dataGrid at the beginning

```
public void fillGrid()
    {

        using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            sc.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM object";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, sc);

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                adapter.Update(dt);
                //  dataGridSvi.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                dataGridSearch.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + textBoxPlace.Text + "%");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "%" + textBoxType.Text + "%");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", "%" + textBoxCity.Text + "%");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", "%" + textBoxType.Text + "%");
```

check your textboxes, u call same textbox twice. maybe that's the problem

oh and about the reset your grid, you can just call `fillGrid()` one more time when all the textboxes will be clear

Comment: this is just the typo for the stackoverfow question.I have it all entered right in my code.sorry for the typo.also it looks like that for some fields from the database it works fine.but for some it doesn't

Comment: ok, and if u do it with `button` ? not with `textchange event` ?? can u post exact code ??